# Dúvida while sql

Tags: sql, db2

Preciso pegar todos os 5 valores antes do `~3L` da XXX:

```
~1BLB~2B1C~3L~1TPL~2B39~3L~1RAD~2C1D~3L
```

E assim por diante.

Já consegui fazer ele pega o primeiro valor antes do 3L com esse select:

```
db2 "select SUBSTR(FH01XXX.pnrstring,(POSSTR(FH01XXX.pnrstring,'~3L')-5),5) AS PRNR from UFHDBXXX.fh01tXXX'"
```

Só não consigo pensar em uma maneira de ele "varrer" a string novamente para pegar os outros antes do `3L`.

---

Muito obrigado pelas respostas, mas elas ainda não solucionaram meu problema por 2 motivos:

1. Eu recebo essa string de outro sistema, o conteúdo dela é variável, mas sempre haverá esse `"~3L"`.
2. Eu preciso pensar em um while, pois são aproximadamente 20 `"~3L"`, e eu preciso mostrar os 5 caracteres antes de cada `"~3L"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bom dia.

Você poderia tentar.

Pegar antes do ~3L:

`SELECT substring('~1BLB~2B1C~3L~1TPL~2B39~3L~1RAD~2C1D~3L'  from 1 for 10);`

Pegar depois do ~3L:

`SELECT substring('~1BLB~2B1C~3L~1TPL~2B39~3L~1RAD~2C1D~3L'  from 15);`

Utilizando substring para mostrar de um valor até tal valor.

O código utilizado é para o bd PostgreSQL mas contém o mesmo conceito para outros bancos, inclusive SQL.

Abraços.

Answer (score 1):

Você também pode ultilizar `INSTR` para capturar a primeira ocorrência de "~3L"

```
SELECT substring('~1BLB~2B1C~3L~1TPL~2B39~3L~1RAD~2C1D~3L'  from 1 for INSTR('~1BLB~2B1C~3L~1TPL~2B39~3L~1RAD~2C1D~3L', '~3L'));
```